# How to know when we're done with a DataContext?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I'm currently learning WPF and MVVM on my own.

I have a dialog box that is created in my XAML using

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <vm:PreferencesViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
```

The constructor of PreferencesViewModel() calls the LoadConfig() of my PreferencesModel object (loads a XML file).  What I would like to do is call PreferencesModel::SaveConfig() from the PreferencesViewModel when the "OK" button of my dialog box is clicked but I can't since the I don't have access to the PreferencesViewModel object automatically created by `<vm:PreferencesViewModel />`.  I'd do it in the destructor but the GC won't destroy the object.

Is there a way to know when the XAML is done with the PreferencesViewModel object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ...but I can't since the I don't have access to the PreferencesViewModel...

Give it a name and access it in codebehind.

```
<vm:PreferencesViewModel x:Name="MyVM" />
```

Or extract it off of the datacontext in code behind:

```
var myVM = (PreferencesViewModel) DataContext;
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't know we could give a name to that kind of XAML element.  Thanks!

Comment: @PierreFournier I give a no-nonsense way of dealing with MVVM on my blog on an article entitled [Xaml: ViewModel Main Page Instantiation and Loading Strategy for Easier Binding](http://omegacoder.com/?p=1017) which might be of help.